# What is the correct interpretation of the bold part?

Tags: meaning, comprehension, interpretation, metaphors

Does the bold part here mean "so you are in fact not know about the ballerinas digging up the locked cabinet in the dark, even though you know about being in the darkness/ being in the night”?

> The phrase “in the dark,” as I’m sure you know, can refer not only to
> one’s shadowy surroundings, but also to the shadowy secrets of which
> one might be unaware. Every day, the sun goes down over all these
> secrets, and so everyone is in the dark in one way or another. If you
> are sunbathing in a park, for instance, but you do not know that a
> locked cabinet is buried fifty feet beneath your blanket, then you are
> in the dark even though you are not actually in the dark, whereas if
> you are on a midnight hike, knowing full well that several ballerinas
> are following close behind you, then you are not in the dark even if
> you are in fact in the dark. Of course, it is quite possible to be in
> the dark in the dark, as well as to be not in the dark not in the
> dark, but there are so many secrets in the world that it is likely
> that you are always in the dark about one thing or another, whether
> you are in the dark in the dark or in the dark not in the dark,
> although the sun can go down so quickly that you may be in the dark
> about being in the dark in the dark, only to look around and find
> yourself no longer in the dark about being in the dark in the dark,
> but in the dark in the dark nonetheless, not only because of the dark,
> but because of the ballerinas in the dark, who are not in the dark
> about the dark, but also not in the dark about the locked cabinet, and
> you may be in the dark about the ballerinas digging up the locked
> cabinet in the dark, even though you are no longer in the dark about
> being in the dark, **and so you are in fact in the dark about being in
> the dark, even though you are not in the dark about being in the
> dark**, and so you may fall into the hole that the ballerinas have
> dug, which is dark, in the dark, and in the park.

Sourse: "The End," by Daniel Hndler

Comment: Do not try to understand it, just enjoy it.

Comment: Yes. Even though you're aware of the darkness, you don't know what you don't know (i.e., the digging ballerinas)

Comment: Talk about flogging a dead horse! The wordplay here might have been *mildly* amusing for a sentence or two, but any trace of humour gave way to stultifying boredom for me, long before I got anywhere near the highlighted element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This paragraph uses two meanings of the phrase "in the dark":

1. In an area without light
2. Not knowing something, unaware of something

The bold part means

> ... and so you **are unaware of what you are unaware of**, even though you are not **unaware that you are in a place without light**.